# Add a search in html Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using the [DDSlick plugin](http://designwithpc.com/plugins/ddslick) in my website. Everything is fine, I just want to add a filter type of thing in which there is a textbox on top. On entering text it will filter the results.

My current list box:

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
</select>
```

After using DDSlick plugin it becomes:

```
<ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close" style="width: 260px; display: block;">
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option dd-option-selected">
            <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="-1"> 
            <label class="dd-option-text">Please Select From List</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
            <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="26"> 
            <img class="dd-option-image" src="http://localhost/fifa/admin/server/packs/files/large-gold-if%20%284%29.png">
            <label class="dd-option-text">test</label> 
            <small class="dd-option-description dd-desc">test</small>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, then what?  What's the problem?

Comment: @ScottKaye i want to add a search box that filters li items

Answer (score 0):

I believe DDslick does not have the feature that you are looking for.

I would recommend you `bootstrap-select` plugin. [Check it out here.](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) Lookup for the example that is using `data-live-search="true"`.